# JavaScript not catching undefined from localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm clearly missing something obvious.

I simply want to check for undefined. The script in the image is every way I know of to check for undefined, but although you can see in the watch that the value for currentbusiness is "undefined", the script goes through to the final else statement. Why isn't the script going in to any of the undefined checks?

[image]

Comment: Please post text, not images. Not everyone can see images and it's much easier to search text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the value is `"undefined"` (a string, notice the quotes) not `undefined`.

The browser storage (localStorage/sessionStorage) coerces everything into a string when storing it, hence you get back a string no matter what you put inside.

When you coerce `undefined` to a string you get `"undefined"`:

```js
console.log(
  typeof String(undefined), // "string" this is what storage does to undefined
  typeof undefined          // "undefined"
);
```

You can check for this with a single strict comparison `currentBusiness === "undefined"`

Another option would be to just not store `undefined` values, which would then have the storage actually return you `undefined` (not `"undefined"`) when requesting a value that was never stored and thus your checks would work as expected:

```
// assume currentBusiness was never stored in the first place
// because we chose not to store undefined values
localStorage["currentBusiness"] === undefined // true
```

---

Another thing worth pointing out is that you have redundant checks.
Your first `if` condition

```
if (typeof currentBusiness === 'undefined' || !currentBusiness)
```

will be true if the value has type `"undefined"`, which only the value `undefined` has, or the value is falsy, which means it's one of these: `"", 0, false, null, undefined, NaN`.

This means if the value is `undefined` or anything falsy (this is redundant by itself since `undefined` is already falsy), it will always enter the first `if` and the other three checks will never happen because they all check for a falsy value.

As a matter of fact, just a falsy check would cover all your conditions:

```
if (!currentBusiness) // this handles all your individual checks
```

Answer (score 1):

In the right you can see that the value is the string "undefined" and you don't check for that in any of the cases:

1. typeof... -> the type is string
2. the value is not undefined
3. the value is not null
4. (!...) -> the value is truthy

so you get to the last 'else' section

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` converts anything you put in it to strings, so it has the string `"undefined"` in it instead of the value `undefined`. You can check for that the usual way:

```
if (currentBusiness === 'undefined') {
```

but it’s probably better to fix whatever’s setting the value to `undefined` to make it delete from `localStorage` instead:

```
if (valueToStore === undefined) {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentBusiness');
} else {
    localStorage.setItem('currentBusiness', valueToStore);
}
```